# ¿Cómo enlazar un ID con varias spreadsheets con Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito saber como puedo enlazar un ID con un nombre algo así,

`Nombre ID`    ---------`Nombre ID`
 `Juan   1`     ----------`Juan   1`
  `Jose   2`   ----------`Juan   1`
  `Carlos 3` 
     ----------`Juan 1`

Imaginando que la columna de la izquierda es una spreadsheet y la de la derecha es otra spreadsheet y que si agrego un nombre y un ID a la spreadsheet de la izquierda, se enlacen los dos para que cuando en la otra spreadsheet se me ocurre que mediante una formula si coloco el ID, me traiga el nombre enlazado con ese ID.

Comment: ¿Por qué si el último ID es 3 el nuevo ID es 5? ¿Qué pasó con el 4?

Comment: Es solo un ejemplo no es  realmente en lo que estoy trabajando jeje

Comment: Bueno, si está dado que algo ingresará el Nombre y el ID y esto no es lo importante, sólo tienes que agregar el enlace a las demás hojas. ¿Qué has intentado y en que parte te encuentras atorado? ¿A que te refieres con enlace, acaso a un URL?

Comment: No, a una URL no, mas bien que si tengo en una spreadsheet en la que voy agregando un nombre y un ID que automaticamente cada vez que ese ID lo utilice en otra spreadsheet como una formula, ponga el nombre al lado de ese ID automáticamente, algo asi como `function ID() {  var nombre = " nombre"     }` pero que cada ID que vaya agregando en la spreadsheet automáticamente detecte el nombre y se agregue ese ID con ese nombre sin tener que agregarlo en el código no se si me explico. Puedo modificar la pregunta para explicarlo mejor?

Comment: Claro que puedes modificar la pregunta para explicarlo mejor, de hecho es una de las características de este sitio, las publicaciones se pueden modificar en cualquier momento pero debe hacerse para mejorar la publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar funciones de hoja de cálculo como [COINCIDIR (MATCH)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=es) para encontrar la posición del primer valor de un rango que coincida con un valor especificado.

Luego puedes usar otra función de hoja de cálculo como [INDICE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=es) para obtener el un valor de un rango con base en la posición obtenida por COINCIDIR.

La fórmula quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
=INDICE('Hoja 1'!A2:A,COINCIDIR(B2,'Hoja 1'!B2:B,FALSO))
```

Si por "spreadsheet" te refieres a otro archivo, primero deberás usar [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=es) para importar los datos del otro archivo. Podrías hacer la importación en Hoja 1 y así no tienes que modificar la fórmula anterior.

Podrías usar Apps Script para crear funciones personalizadas pero en muchos casos las funciones de hoja de cálculo se desempeñan mejor en particular porque la mayoría se ejecuta del lado del cliente mientras que las funciones personalizadas se ejecutan en el servidor, además estas tiene limitaciones como un máximo de 30 segundos de tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Es que quiero entender mejor como funcionan estas funciones en un script ya que pueden ser bastantes datos los que tenga que enlazar y en un script puedo modificar todo a mi gusto o a mi manera, casi lo logro con unos ejemplos que he estado viendo, hago de nuevo una pregunta nueva ruben?  Gracias por tu apoyo saludos :)

Comment: @LuisAvl : Como en esta pregunta dices "se me ocurre que mediante una formula (sic) ..." me parece que era pertinente responderte como lo hice y que deberías publicar una nueva pregunta en la que procures ser más específico e incluir una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado.